# How to know which are the 5 first characters in a string

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an iPad app, where, if the `TextField.text` starts with 5 specific characters, it will do one thing, and else if it doesn't start with it, will do a different action. Any idea of how to know the 5 first characters of a  `NSString` ?

Comment: Did you try to look in the Apple documentation for such a basic question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ([someString hasPrefix:@"hello"]) { ... }
```

Or, if you want to find out what the first five characters are instead of comparing against a specific string, you can do this instead:

```
NSString *firstFive = [someString substringToIndex:MIN(5, [someString length])];
```

Comment: OK. It is all I need, and I knew it will be answered fast, because it's a silly question ;) .Thank you man!

Comment: Caveat: the second method may raise an `NSRangeException`, so you should check `[someString length]` before sending `substringToIndex:`. The first method is safe.